# npm install extremely slow on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, performance, npm

This question was asked a lot of times here on Stackoverflow, though no suggestion fixes it for me. What I've tried:

- disabled windows security real-time protection and windows defender firewall
- disabled progress bar (take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283))
- reset registry (as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663198/npm-install-is-extremely-slow) points)
- performed complete nodeJS and npm uninstall
- yes, network is good (I even tested npm within my neighbour's net: no way)

I'm not sure if the issue affects other commands: npm -v takes nearly 1 second to execute: it's longer than `node -v`, but perhaps still within normal.

Not a hardware issue: on ubuntu, performance is perfect.

npm version: 6.14.4 
nodeJS version: 12.16.3